# Combining gnu parallel and mpirun: how to take care of the max number of cores?

Tags: gnu-parallel, mpi

I have a machine with 32 cores where a I want to run some mpi jobs with a variable number of cores (this is because the problem requires that). Is there a way to make gnu parallel aware of the number of mpi jobs to manage when to launch each job?

Example:
Let's say that I have to launch many (200) jobs with following number of mpi jobs:

```
NMPI=(2 2 2 4 4 4 4 6 7 10 12 24 32)
```

Therefore, initially I want to only run the first 8 elements of the array (since their total sum is less that the total number of cores, 32), and then run sequentially each other job gradually as soon as each of the firsts are finished, without surpassing the limit of 32 total concurrent mpi jobs. 
For example, let's assume that the first 8 process were running, and the first one just finished (for the first NMPI[0] == 2). Then parallel should not run anything new until enough processors are free, since the next job has NMPI[8]==7 and therefore will surpass the maximum limit of 32 cores. 
Or is there a way for parallel to improve the job launching , like launching first the last mpi job (32 cores) then the last minus one plus the first three and so on?

Thanks in advance for your guidance

Answer (score 0):

Flip the order of the array, so starting with the biggest job first.

Maybe you can use `--load 100%` and `--delay 10s` so you are sure the job uses all cores before starting the next?